# how to set more than one menus to the same theme location

Tags: theme-development, menus

In my theme i need to display different left side menus on different pages. so i register a secondary menu too by this

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary' => __( 'Top Menu' ),
      'left' => __( 'Left Menu' )
    )
  );
```

and i used a plugin named `CE WP-Menu per Page` to select menus from dropdown list shown in the page edit, so that i can assign different menu for different pages. and in my page template i wrote the below code to display the menus

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-left-side-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'theme_location' => 'left' ) );
```

In Dashboard->Appearnce->menus i have created 3 menus (for test, actually no: of menus depends on no: of pages created). They are

```
1.top menu
2. left menu1
3. left menu2
```

and  had assigned `primary` for top menu and `left` for left menu1. everything worked perfectly. but i have to assign left menu2 for another page and display it. for that when i assign left menu2 to location `left` , previous assignement of left menu1 overwrites. and now left menu1 is not showing in the page.

**Problem**

Is there any way to make the wordpress menu supports assigning more than one menus to same menu theme location??

I hope my problem description is understandable. if any clarification needed please tell me.

Comment: Why do you want to do that. You can simply add as many menu as you want in a single container for further CSS styling.

Comment: I need to display different set of menus for each page. that is page1 should show menu1 , page2 should show menu2 and so on. but all these menus must be displayed in same div location. if i create different theme locations separate for each menu then it will be numerous. thats why i thought of this method. if you know a better way to solve my issue please share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) to define different menu items as you want.

```
if ( is_page( 'About' ) ) {

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-left-side-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'theme_location' => 'about-page' ) );

} elseif ( is_page( 'Services' ) ) {

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-left-side-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'theme_location' => 'services-page' ) );

} elseif ( is_page( 'Contact' ) ) {

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-left-side-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'theme_location' => 'contact-page' ) );

} else {

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-left-side-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'theme_location' => 'default-menu' ) );

}
```

And you can define as many menu as you want in your theme.

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'about-page' => __( 'About Page Menu' ),
        'services-page' => __( 'Services Page Menu' ),
        'contact-page' => __( 'Contact Page Menu' ),
        'default-page' => __( 'Default Page Menu' ),
        'left' => __( 'Left Menu' )
    )
);
```

If you don't want to use many menus then you can simply add all items in one single menu and hide non-required menu items on each page with the help of [WordPress body classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and CSS styles.